# Run Safari browser headlessly using xvfb on Mac

Tags: macos, safari, xvfb, headless-browser, js-test-driver

How do I run my jstestdriver test cases headlessly on Safari browser on OSX platform?
I am able to achieve the same on Linux by using xvfb-run command. However, there is no such wrapper command available in OSX. I tried executing the following 2 commands and then executing my testcases in safari.

```
Xvfb :99 -ac &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

However, by Safari browser shows up instead of running in xvfb environment. It seems like Safari ignores the DISPLAY command completely. Is there a way I can run Safari headlessly on OSX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mac OS X does not use X11 as the display server for native applications. As such, Xvfb is not applicable, and setting `DISPLAY` has no effect.

Mac OS applications cannot generally be run in the same sort of "headless" environment you're imagining here. Some applications, such as [Vine Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/osxvnc/), could do this in the past, but they appear to have stopped working under Mac OS 10.8 and later.